# Centering h1 in a header

Tags: html, css, header, position, centering

I wanna center my h1 element in the header, but it just won't work. It should be in the middle of the 450px header, while the nav bar stays at the right top. And if possible I wanna put in a logo at the top left. I've tried it with align, position and margin auto. If anyone could help and show me my error, that'll be nice, thanks.

```css
body {
  background-color: #999;
  font-family: times;
}
header {
  height: 450px;
  background: url(../Pictures/Flensburg.jpg) center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}
nav {
  float: right;
  30px 30px 0 0;
}
ul{
  display: inline;
  align: right;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 10px
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px
}
a {
  background-color: #b3b3b3;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 72px
  width: 100%
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Keanu</title>
    <link href="CSS/Main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
    <nav>
      <ul>
    <li><a href="Index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="About Me.html">About Me</a></li>
    <li><a href="Portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a href="Testimonial.html">Testimonial</a></li>
    <li><a href="Contact.html">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
  </nav>
  <h1>My Personal Website</h1>
</header>
<footer>

</footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you want the nav and the h1 to be in the same line? Can you upload a picture with what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should make sure, that your markup and your CSS rules are valid. A rule `align: right` i.e. doesn't exist in CSS. Also you forgot a `;` in your h1 CSS rules.

To center your h1, you can just put `text-align: center;` on it, while making the `nav` element `display: block;` to let it stay in its own line.

```css
body {
  background-color: #999;
  font-family: Times;
}

header {
  height: 450px;
  background: url(../Pictures/Flensburg.jpg) center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}

ul {
  display: block;
  text-align: right;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 10px;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
}

a {
  background-color: #b3b3b3;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 72px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="Index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="About Me.html">About Me</a></li>
      <li><a href="Portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li><a href="Testimonial.html">Testimonial</a></li>
      <li><a href="Contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <h1>My Personal Website</h1>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `display: inline-block;`, `text-align: center;` and `width: 100%;` to the h1 heading.

```
h1 {
    font-size: 72px;

    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Full Edited code below:

```css
body {
  background-color: #999;
  font-family: times;
}
header {
  height: 450px;
  background: url(../Pictures/Flensburg.jpg) center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}
nav {
  float: right;
  30px 30px 0 0;
}
ul{
  display: inline;
  align: right;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 10px
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px
}
a {
  background-color: #b3b3b3;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 72px;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="Index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="About Me.html">About Me</a></li>
      <li><a href="Portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li><a href="Testimonial.html">Testimonial</a></li>
      <li><a href="Contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <h1>My Personal Website</h1>
</header>
<footer>

</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix a couple of the issues with the following css adjustments:

1) adding width: 100% to you nav element

2) adding width:100% to your h1 element

3) adding text-align: center to your h1 element

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
  background-color: #999;
  font-family: times;
}
header {
  height: 450px;
  background: url(../Pictures/Flensburg.jpg) center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}
nav {
  float: right;
  30px 30px 0 0;
}
ul{
  display: inline;
  align: right;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 10px
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px
}
a {
  background-color: #b3b3b3;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 72px
  width: 100%;
text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Keanu</title>
    <link href="CSS/Main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
    <nav>
      <ul>
    <li><a href="Index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="About Me.html">About Me</a></li>
    <li><a href="Portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a href="Testimonial.html">Testimonial</a></li>
    <li><a href="Contact.html">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
  </nav>
  <h1>My Personal Website</h1>
</header>
<footer>

</footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem originally stems from your floated `<nav>`. You haven't cleared the float, meaning that the following element (the h1) is influenced by the floated nav.

Adding a div with `clear:both` after your `</nav>` solves the problem. However, as pointed out by the others, you still have a lot of errors in your code (missing semicolons and a margin or padding line which only includes the numbers, and not the actual styling property) and you still need to apply a `text-align:center` to your h1 if you want the text to be centered. I've corrected and done this in the code beneath.

```css
body {
  background-color: #999;
  font-family: times;
}
header {
  height: 450px;
  background: url(../Pictures/Flensburg.jpg) center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}
nav {
  float: right;
  /* The previous line beneath was "30px 30px 0 0;" - I assumed you wanted a margin. Change if not */
  margin: 30px 30px 0 0;
}
ul{
  display: inline;
  align: right;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 10px;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
}
a {
  background-color: #b3b3b3;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 72px;
  width: 100%;
text-align:center;
}
.clear{
clear:both;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Keanu</title>
    <link href="CSS/Main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
    <nav>
      <ul>
    <li><a href="Index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="About Me.html">About Me</a></li>
    <li><a href="Portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a href="Testimonial.html">Testimonial</a></li>
    <li><a href="Contact.html">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
  </nav>
<div class="clear"></div>
  <h1>My Personal Website</h1>
</header>
<footer>

</footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

Edit:
Note that if you do not clear the float and correct your errors in the css, thereby getting a font-size of 72px, it will appear as if the elements are aligned correctly. However your `h1` will still lie behind your `nav` and the problem isn't actually fixed. If you choose to decrease the font size, the problem will appear again.